# How to retrieve the value of a get request in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js

I'm trying to retrieve data in a javascript object, The object was generated from a get request to an API and the in the network console i can clearly see the response as {"number":"141"} but whenever i try to print the result of the query i get this type of object, which contain the value i want:

In the console :

```
Object { _c: [], _a: undefined, _s: 0, _d: false, _v: undefined, _h: 0, _n: false }
```

But when i expend the value

```
{
  "_c": [],
  "_s": 1,
  "_d": true,
  "_v": {
    "data": {
      "number": "141"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "headers": {
      "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8"
    },
    "config": {
     [...]
}
```

But every time i try it appears that i cannot access the value using just tab['_v'].
I'v tried multiple things such as :

```
for (var key in x) {
            console.log(x[key])
        }
```

to try to print the "_v" part but
i'm not enable to list the "_v" part of the array/object.

Steps to obtain such result :

**.vue file that call the function**

```
export default {
    mounted() {

    var x=this.connectionsAlive()
    console.log(x)
    for (var property in x) {
        console.log(property)
    }
},
methods: {
        ...mapActions({
            connectionsAlive: 'mkt/connectionsAlive',
        })
    }
}
```

**Then it goes to a file called mkt-module.js and then mkt-api.js**

```
---mkt-module---
import { connectionsAlive } from '@/api/mkt-api'
export default {
    namespaced: true,
    state: {
        test: '',

    },
    actions: {
        connectionsAlive() {
            const response = connectionsAlive()
            return response

        }
    }
}
----mkt-api----
import axios from 'axios'
import { getAbsoluteUrl } from '@/services/url-service'

export const connectionsAlive = () => (
    axios.get(`/api/DeviceEvents/connectionsAlive`)
)
```

**And the response body i get is :**

```
JSON :
number : 141
```

But when i try to print it i get the result at the top of this post.

I'm clearly missing something or just knowledge about the structure. If anyone has an idea i'll gadly take the help, thanks.

Comment: Can you show us how are you making this get request? Are you making a get request within Node.js or Vue.js?

Comment: yes of course i'll copy that, it is a vue.js request to a loopback API

Comment: Do you have any errors? Posting also the error could be useful, I tried your code and it's working for what you pasted, I think we need more info as josephting said.

Comment: i'll paste the result of the iteration

Comment: It seems that you are taking an empty object in input. Have you checked the request/response body? Please to details your question copy your whole code where you are doing the operation and with request and response to/from the server.

Comment: I tried to make it clearer, tell me if you need something

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the

```
connectionsAlive
```

method does an http calls to the server, it is an asynchronous operation. 
 You should append a .then() to this.connectionsAlive()

```
this.connectionsAlive().then(x => {
    console.log(x)
    for (var property in x) {
        console.log(property)
    }
})
```

I have not tried it, but hope it could help you to spot the problem.
You can find further reading about Promises here: https://hackernoon.com/understanding-promises-in-javascript-13d99df067c1

Comment: When i tried to add the "return" i got a syntax error, but otherwise i tried to use .then and everything worked.

based on what you said i wrote this : 
        this.connectionsAlive().then(x => {
            console.log(x.data.number)
        })

And everything is working fine thanks !

Comment: Good, I'll edit the answer to keep it the correct way. You're welcome!